# EditText with TextWatcher repeating after validation Android

Tags: java, android, validation, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have a `EditText` with a Mask "##-###.###" and the result is 11-111.111, so I decided to use a TextWatch, so I did..

```
cepFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() == 10){
                //getCepFrom(s.toString());
                Toast.makeText(DetalhesProdutos.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Which will consume a WebService, but just for testing, the Toast with the OK message, executes twice and I dont' know why...

Comment: Move `Toast.makeText(DetalhesProdutos.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to  `afterTextChanged`

Comment: it kept repeating, like it was in some loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
   cepFrom.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     if(cepFrom.getText().length() == 10){
            //getCepFrom(s.toString());
            Toast.makeText(DetalhesProdutos.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i think your put code for  Toast some where by mistake check it,,because its working for me